# ¿Que significa : bad variable name?

Tags: linux, bash

`read -p "Hola, ¿cual es tu nombre?" name`

`echo "${name}"`

al ejecutar, me pregunta cual es mi nombre pero despues me sale:

`: bad variable nameame`

he probado a poner distinos nombre a la variable por si acaso y nada

Comment: Revisa tambien, la shell que usas a ver si tu SO utiliza bash u otra, quizas te este dando errores eso o algún espacio, que bash es muy nazi con eso.

Comment: @JorgeG. si, estoy usando /bin/bash respecto a los datos de entrada que introduzco he probado con caracteres simples, incluso he llegado a probar solo con letras y nada

Comment: Prueba esto en tu terminal y dime que te sale **echo $SHELL** deberia salirte /bin/bash si es otra osa, tu problema va por ahí

Comment: @JorgeG. sim /bin/bash

Comment: Prueba con **printf "\nHola, ${name}"**. Si no son espacios en blanco que se te hayan colado, es que tu shell o algo relacionado con ello no esta interpretando bien cuando declaras variables. Que sistema operativo estas utilizando?

Comment: Añade por favor todo el código, así como la manera en que lo ejecutas

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' ese es todo el codigo

Comment: ¿Adónde apunta tu `/bin/bash`? Haz `ls -l /bin/bash` pues parece que se está ejecutando otra cosa

Answer (score 0):

Ese código funciona, te pregunta el nombre, metes lo que sea y te sale. Has de meter el  input sin comillas ni carateres extraños, pero funcionar te deberia funcionar. Si puedes explicar algo más que nombres estas metiendo y demas..

Te adjunto la salida de mi terminal con ese mismo código

```
#!/bin/bash 

read -p "Hola, ¿cual es tu nombre?" name
echo "Hola, ${name}"
```

y el output:

> Hola, jorge

Dale permisos de ejecucion con: chmod +x TUSCRIPTNAME.sh